# Android Application - error while opening URL that uses WebRTC in WebView

Tags: android, webview, webrtc

I am working on developing an Android application, in which I want to open a URL in WebView. Now, if I open a simple URL in WebView (like www.google.com) is works just fine. But I want to open a URL which uses WebRTC (Web Real-Time Communication) which errs stating: "Looks like you are using unsupported browser version". I searched on google.com and found that WebRTC starts supporting from Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher.

My version of Webview is:

using `webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString()` i get my webview details.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; Android SDK built for x86 Build/PSR1.180720.075; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

My build.gradle (Module:app) is as follows :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.cbtech.learningpod"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner 

"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}


configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "26.+"
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
    implementation('com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.3.3') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml file is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="com.cbtech.learningpod">

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.webkit.WebView.EnableSafeBrowsing"
            android:value="false" />
        <!--<meta-data
            android:name="android.webkit.WebView.EnableSafeBrowsing"
            android:value="false" />-->

        <activity
            android:name=".views.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
       Add this activity to your manifest
       it comes with the Paytm SDK
       -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPGActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MyFragment.java file is as follows :

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    String url;
    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    final String CUSTOM_TAB_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.android.chrome";
    CustomTabsClient mCustomTabsClient;
    CustomTabsSession mCustomTabsSession;
    CustomTabsServiceConnection mCustomTabsServiceConnection;
    CustomTabsIntent mCustomTabsIntent;


    public static MyFragment newInstance(String url) {
        BBBFragment fragment = new BBBFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("URL", url);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            url = getArguments().getString("URL");
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myfragment, container, false);
        webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webviewBBB);
        try {
            Log.d("BBB URL is ", url);

            Log.d("WebView Version", "=======>" + webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString());
            //   webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webviewBBB);
            //setUpWebViewDefaults(webView);
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebClient());
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 5 Build/LMY48B; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Mobile Safari/537.36");

            // AppRTC requires third party cookies to work
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
            webView.loadUrl(url);
            //webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
            //webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dXnrvvCFG4");

         /*   CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
            CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
            customTabsIntent.launchUrl(getActivity(), Uri.parse(url));*/

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return view;
    }

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(
                WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            Log.i("Tag", "page started:" + url);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            Log.i("Tag", "page finished:" + url);
        }

        //Show loader on url load
        public void onLoadResource(final WebView view, String url) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
            //Open the Custom Tab
            intentBuilder.build().launchUrl(getContext(), uri);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError er) {
            handler.proceed();
        }

    }

    private class MyWebClient extends WebChromeClient {

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request) {
            super.onPermissionRequest(request);
            request.grant(request.getResources());
        }


    }


    /**
     * Convenience method to set some generic defaults for a
     * given WebView
     *
     * @param webView
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void setUpWebViewDefaults(WebView webView) {
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

        // Enable Javascript
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Use WideViewport and Zoom out if there is no viewport defined
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        // Enable pinch to zoom without the zoom buttons
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        // Allow use of Local Storage
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            // Hide the zoom controls for HONEYCOMB+
            settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        }

        // Enable remote debugging via chrome://inspect
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.canGoBack();
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.getSettings().setSafeBrowsingEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 5 Build/LMY48B; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Mobile Safari/537.36");

        // AppRTC requires third party cookies to work
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
    }
}
```

here is the link of screenshot   https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzl8L.png

Answer (score 0):

please add this to method to your WebviewClient

```
  private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {

     .
     .
     .

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        return true;
    }

     .
     .
     .

 }
```

try this.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void setUpWebViewDefaults(WebView webView) {
 .

 .
 .

 .

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
        }
    });

 .
 . 
 .
}
```

Accept Regarding permission runtime. Search Serious runtime permission grant permission

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I added the above code but it does not effect my error.Please check the screenshot of the error.

Comment: Hi, I tried the above code  but it does not effect my error.